# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.Net MVC 2 and 3 installed.  I've downloaded the complete source from github for the Rob Connery MVC Storefront [here](https://github.com/robconery/MVC-Storefront).  I've opened it in VS2010, which ran the conversion wizard.  When I launch it though, I get the error in the title, on the following line `<li><a href="<%=Url.Action("About", "Home") %>">About</a></li>` which is line 24 in Site.Master.  So I'm thinking, ah, this thing is still referencing v1 of MVC, instead of v2.  So the first thing I checked is the  section of the web.config, thinking that must be where the reference to version 1 of MVC is residing, however, I found the following `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />`.  Even in the Project References, the reference properties for System.Web.Mvc show that it is referencing v2.0 from the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies.  Does anyone have advice on where I can find the reference to the v1.0.0.0 of System.Web.Mvc so that I can change this to v2 in order to make the above error go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most probable cause for this exception is that you are referencing some assembly in your project that implicitly depends on System.Web.Mvc 1.0. For example you might be using some DI framework which is compiled against MVC 1. So if you have ensured that in your web.config you have the correct version and that it is the correct version being referenced you might go through all other assemblies that are referenced in your project and see if they don't depend on MVC 1.0.

Comment: thanks I found it...turns out the Microsoft.Web.Mvc dll had to be updated to the one for MVC 2.  (I found this by opening the dll in Reflector to explore its references.)

Comment: @ShawndeWet. Start using `nuget`!

Comment: +1 for helping me to understand that I can find the issue by using reflector